# Unity can't render more when 3 light points. Why?

Tags: unity, rendering

[YouTube video](https://youtu.be/L4AwmUoQESc) with demonstration of problem.
When I move the camera, Unity keeps rendering one light point and stops rendering another one. But as a result, only 3 can be rendered. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is likely to be an in-editor behaviour to give priority to performance rather than visual quality when editing a scene. Do you encounter the same issue when playing the scene?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/maximum-number-of-lights-in-scene.667054/